# Как правильно писать структуру проекта Java Intellij?

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, структуры, проект, data-structures, project

Как правильно писать структуру проекта, ее уровни?
Кажись вначале должен быть один путь для всех последующих пакетов (`java.com.corporation`).

- `.controlle` - здесь находятся контроллеры,
- `.entity` - сущности,
- `.dao` - слой который обеспечивает доступ к `БД`,
- `.service` - это что-то вроде посредника между `DAO` и к примеру контроллером,
- `.heandler` - как я понимаю обработчик данных,

но также есть и другие слои, такие как: `business`, `object`,  ...

Пожалуйста опешите доходчиво какие есть уровни и какое их предназначение!

Comment: Нет никаких четких правил. В одних проектах нарезают пакеты по слоям, в других - по функциональным срезам, в третьих - по границе доменной модели, в четыертых - все валят в один пакет. Главное, чтобы классы, сильно связанные друг с другом, имели общий родительский пакет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот здесь описана структура мавен проекта, но и вы его можете придерживаться - https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_make_my_first_Maven_project. Если нужен пакет типа dao, добавьте его в самой нижней паке, то есть под "coproration".

Comment: Это всё-таки русский SO, а ссылка на ресурс на английском языке. Думаю, "опешите доходчиво какие есть уровни и какое их предназначение" значило немного другое :)

Comment: Можно не читать. Там ведь главное это схема папок. Был бы я сейчас не на линуксе, сделал бы скрин. А в линуксе, чтобы сделать любое элементарное действие нужно полчаса потратить.